# Resource https://av.by/ is not available at ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

When I try to fetch some data from https://av.by/ using AWS Lambda or EC2 I got 423 status code error.
VPC is created and added to Lambda, but response is the same.

I'm trying to fetch using node.js

```
const contentJson = await fetch(
      'https://api.av.by/offer-types/cars/filters/main/apply',
      {
        headers: {
          accept: '*/*',
          'accept-language': 'ru,nl;q=0.9',
          'content-type': 'application/json',
          'sec-ch-ua':
            '"Not_A Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="120", "Google Chrome";v="120"',
          'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
          'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"macOS"',
          'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
          'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
          'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
          'x-device-type': 'web.desktop',
          Referer: 'https://cars.av.by/',
          'Referrer-Policy': 'strict-origin-when-cross-origin',
        },
        body: '{"page":2,"properties":[{"name":"price_currency","value":2}],"sorting":4}',
        method: 'POST',
      },
);
```

And got this response:

```
Response {
  [Symbol(realm)]: null,
  [Symbol(state)]: {
    aborted: false,
    rangeRequested: false,
    timingAllowPassed: true,
    requestIncludesCredentials: true,
    type: 'default',
    status: 423,
    timingInfo: {
      startTime: 19720.235054999997,
      redirectStartTime: 0,
      redirectEndTime: 0,
      postRedirectStartTime: 19720.235054999997,
      finalServiceWorkerStartTime: 0,
      finalNetworkResponseStartTime: 0,
      finalNetworkRequestStartTime: 0,
      endTime: 0,
      encodedBodySize: 0,
      decodedBodySize: 0,
      finalConnectionTimingInfo: null
    },
    cacheState: '',
    statusText: '',
    headersList: HeadersList {
      cookies: null,
      [Symbol(headers map)]: [Map],
      [Symbol(headers map sorted)]: null
    },
    urlList: [ [URL] ],
    body: { stream: undefined }
  },
  [Symbol(headers)]: HeadersList {
    cookies: null,
    [Symbol(headers map)]: Map(5) {
      'server' => [Object],
      'date' => [Object],
      'content-length' => [Object],
      'connection' => [Object],
      'keep-alive' => [Object]
    },
    [Symbol(headers map sorted)]: null
  }
}
```

I expect to get fetched data from resource with 200 status code

Comment: I get a 423 from my local browser too.

Comment: 423 Locked is a response from the server.  That means you successfully reached the server and it successfully responded.   So you can rule out networking configuration.  I agree with @Cloudlady's analysis

Answer (score 3):

That's an unusual HTTP status code (423) meaning "locked". As a test I ran "curl" from a non-AWS system and at first I got a 400 error. But, that was because I didn't pass the content-type header. Once I added that, I got a lot of results:

```
~$ curl -s -H 'content-type: application/json' -d '{"page":2,"properties":[{"name":"price_currency","value":2}],"sorting":4}' https://api.av.by/offer-types/cars/filters/main/apply | jq -r . | more
```

{
"count": 68418,
"pageCount": 2737,
"page": 2,
"adverts": [
{
"id": 106200536,
"originalDaysOnSale": 48,
"advertType": "cars",
"status": "active",
"publicStatus": {
"label": "Активное",
"name": "active"
},
"price": {
"usd": {
"currency": "usd",
"amount": 12250,
"amountFiat": 12250
},

Then I ran the same command from an EC2 instance within AWS, and sure enough, I get the 423 HTTP status code. I wonder if that site is blocking requests from AWS and are erroneously returning a 423 error instead of something more appropriate? I don't know if you can contact them, but if so, you might open a support ticket, or something, to see if they can answer why they are not responding to requests that are coming from an AWS resource.